# If a nuget package dependencies is on .NetFramework and .NetStandard - is it compatible with .Net core and runs on Linux?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget, compatibility, serilog

I have a confusion to install one nuget package, example:
Serilog.Sinks.Async - if we see this package in nuget console, it says Dependencies are:
.NetFramework 4.5 / 4.6.1 and also .NetStandard

We are running an Asp.Net core application and will be hosted on Linux server, if this package is dependent on .NetFramework, will it run on Linux/Ubuntu platform?

[image]

Comment: .NET Core is .NET Standard compatible. The docs explain which version is compatible with which one. And Serilog works everywhere

Comment: That list isn't "inclusive" -- like: you need .NETFramework, AND .NETStandard, AND ... It means it supports .NETFramework, OR .NETStandard...

Comment: Does it mean it works on Linux platform?

Comment: There is not guarantee that anything runs on Linux. Contact the vendor/developers for such information.

Comment: A few useful concepts: 

1. Your application targets .NET Core. .NET Core runs on linux. As long as the tooling restores and builds correctly, your application is likely to run on linux. Ofc things are not always perfect, but NETStandard, NETCore were written with cross platform support in mind

2. A package can support many frameworks. What you are seeing is the package qualifying its dependencies for each framework it supports. If you inspect the package you will see different assemblies. 

Ref: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/cross-platform-targeting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *dependencies is on .NetFramework **and** .NetStandard*

It's not an **and**. It's an **or**. NuGet packages have the ability to [target multiple frameworks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks), and this is what's happening here.

`Serilog.Sinks.Async` (as of your screenshot) [targets 4 different frameworks](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-async/blob/v1.4.0/src/Serilog.Sinks.Async/Serilog.Sinks.Async.csproj#L8): `net45`, `netstandard1.1`, `net461`, and `netstandard2.0`, which means it can be consumed by applications (or libraries) built with the full .NET Framework as well as .NET Core apps and other .NET Standard libraries.

The fact it targets .NET Standard or .NET Core App tells you that's it's very likely that the library works on Linux, but there's no guarantee. You can confirm with the maintainers of the project by asking in the [Gitter chat](https://gitter.im/serilog/serilog), or by opening an issue in the [source code repository](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-async) on GitHub.